# Any line intersect with $bd(S)$ at at most two points. Then $S$ or $S^c$ must be convex.

Tags: general-topology, geometry

> Let $S$ be an open set on $\mathbb R^2$. $bd(S)$ is its boundary.
>
> We've known that any line intersect with $bd(S)$ at at most two points.
>
> Is it possible to show that one of the following conditions must hold?
>
> (1) $S$ is connected convex or $S^c$ is connected convex
>
> (2) $bd(S)$ is a discrete set

I first try to show that $S$ is connected by contradiction. Suppose $S$ is not connected. That is, there exists open sets $A,B\subset S$ such that $A\cap B=\emptyset$.

Then, there must exists a line crossing both $A,B$, and the line does not tangent their boundary (how to prove the existence of this line???)

This contradicts to the assumption that any line only intersect with $bd(S)$ twice.

Similarly, we can show that $S^c$ must either have empty interior, or $S^c$ is connected.

Therefore $bd(S)$ must be also connected.

Then suppose that $S$ is not convex. By definition, there exists two points, $x,y\in bd(S)$, such that, for some $a\in (0,1)$, $z=ax+(1-a)y$ does not belong to $S$. If the previous statement holds, then we have for any $a\in (0,1)$, $z=ax+(1-a)y$ does not belong to $S$.

This implies that $S^c$ is connected and convex?

Comment: Does $S^c$ mean the complement of $S$, or the closure? If complement: Consider $C = \{(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2 : x^2 + y^2 = 1, \lvert x\rvert \geqslant 1/2\}$, and $S = \mathbb{R}^2 \setminus C$. Then $C$ is the boundary as well as the complement of $S$, and it's not connected. $S$ is connected and open, but not convex.

Comment: @PaulFrost Thank you for pointing it out! The problem was slightly altered